# Is the frequency necessary to be same to increase the RAM?

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron

I have a laptop that is almost 8 years old now and works really good but the question is, it has 3 Gb of Ram that is 2+1 where i want to increase the ram to 4GB now. It is the following description - 1gb DDR3 667mhz pc3-10700, but all i am getting as a replacement are of higher bandwidth of 1333MHZ. Where can i get the same of 667MHZ or can i use the 1333MHZ.
Please help.

Comment: You can use fastest RAM as far it's supported by motherboard, it will switch automatically to the lowest speed of other (slow) RAM module(s)

Answer (score 0):

Different memory frequencies can be mixed use as long as they are in the same generation, for example, they are all DDR3 regardless of their sizes.

[image]

Based on your description, you have the "1GB DDR3 667mhz"， so you can use the 1333mhz.